# Non-Inverting Tri-State buffer with transistors only possible?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates, tri-state

I'm currently playing around with discrete transistor logic gates and now want to create a tri-state buffer.

The only circuit that I found that kind-of works is [this one](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/wikifiles/4/4c/Tristate.png), but it inverts my input:

[image: inverting tristate buffer]

Putting an inverter in front of it, will cause the T2 to be open, and therefore connect the output to the ground, which is not really what I want for a tristate buffer.

Putting an inverter behind the gate will cause the output to be connected to ground via the inverter-gate. Also not what I want.

Is there a non-inverting tristate circuit which I can build with NPN/PNP BJT transistors only?

Comment: well... you could always just use two of those inverters.

Comment: Or could just run the inverter output to pin 2 and the data input to pin 6.

Comment: @Felthry what would be the purpose of that?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm not sure I understand. Can you draw me a circuit?

Comment: Use two inverting buffers. That makes one non-inverting buffer, with twice the propagation delay.

Comment: @Felthry that doesn't solve my problem of a non-functioning tristate buffer, as far as I can tell

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your problem, then. I thought your problem was that your buffer inverted its output?

Comment: Rather, move the inverter from the input of the lower NAND to the upper one.

Comment: Replacing the NAND gates in the circuit with AND gates is also a possible solution

Answer (score 4):

Your linked circuit shows what is essentially a 74125 buffer on the left side.
TI's [SN74125/126 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/SN54LS125A) shows how the TTL tri-state buffers are implemented (the only difference between '125 and '126 is the polarity of the tri-state input):

[image: SN74125/SN75126 schematic]

(TTL chips used only NPN transistors, so the output cannot go up V<sub>CC</sub>.)

Comment: so if I understand correctly, there is no simpler circuit with BJT transistors only?

Comment: In the Good Old Times™, logic chips were made only with NPN transistors. I guess PNPs would make it easer. (An open-collector buffer would be trivial.)

Comment: PNP wouldn't be a problem. But as I want to create a bigger logic circuit, having several tristate buffers made from a dozend transistors each, would be quite a pain. That's why I'm looking for a simple NPN/PNP BJT cuircuit.

Now looking into open collector stuff, to check if I can use that instead