# Implementing three-state logic

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, logic-gates, tri-state

Can we build a three-state logic gate using only transistors (or basic logic gates)? If so, how is it built?

I'm trying to build a model for an 8-bit computer in LogiSim, and I'm trying to find out if it is possible to build everything using transistors, voltage sources, and a clock.

I know that a multiplexer can be used instead, and that it can be implemented by logic gates, but I prefer to use three-state logic gates.

Comment: When you say 3 logic states, are you implying 3 voltage levels?

Comment: Tri nary or  tristate (high, low, hi-z)?

Comment: A tri-state output can be made discretely from one NOR, NOT, and NAND gate, and two logic-level MOSFETs as seen [here](http://denethor.wlu.ca/pc320/lectures/lgctsbeam.pdf) by Terry Sturtevant.

Comment: High, low, and high-Z is not the same as ternary logic.

Comment: @rdtsc thanks! exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-Inverting Tri-State buffer with transistors only possible?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302564/non-inverting-tri-state-buffer-with-transistors-only-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The logic gates with three state outputs are also made of transistors.

Logisim has transistors, but it also has  buffers and inverters with three state output.

A three state output is like a standard push-pull output, but both the high side and low side output transistors are separately controlled to let them either output a signal in push/pull mode or keep both of them off.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have some source showing how it is built?
I know that I can just use the tools from Logisim, but I'm interested in building them myself fom scratch.

Comment: @RdBasha Wouldn't you just go to the Texas Instruments databook on the 7400 series devices and examine their schematics for "gates with 3-state outputs?" It's there, I believe. I forget what chapter, but it is roughly in the middle of the book.

Comment: @jonk - You're assuming that the hi-Z state is a 3rd logic level.  I'm not sure that's what OP was asking about, and hence my first comment.  Note that Intel way back in the 70's actually implemented ternary logic (3 voltage levels) in one of the PROMs ,IIRC.

Comment: @RdBasha `Do you have some source showing how it is built?` ... you still have not clarified what you are actually asking about

Comment: @SteveSh I did make that assumption. And it could be that one of the trinary (balanced or otherwise) concepts was implied. That said, 'Rd' did happen to respond to the answer here discussing 3-state outputs and didn't disagree. So that may be a small bit of evidence to consider in addition to the question, itself.

Comment: See comments above

Comment: @SteveSh: do you have any more information about these 3 logic levels used in PROMs? It sounds related but not exactly the same as the 3 transistor sizes used to produce 4 voltage levels used in the 8087 microcode ROM in ["high-density ROM in Intel's 8087 floating point chip"](https://www.righto.com/2018/09/two-bits-per-transistor-high-density.html).